# macports svn install not recognized

Tags: macos, svn, macports

My Mac currently has svn version on it 1.7.20
I installed the latest subversion client from macports.  svn is still pointing at /usr/bin/svn where it shouldn't be.  How can I get 'svn' to run through /opt/local/bin/svn as it does with the other active macport apps?

```
$ which svn
/opt/local/bin/svn
$ /opt/local/bin/svn --version
1.9.2_0
$ /usr/bin/svn --version
1.7.20
```

Now, I expect svn --version to produce 1.9.2_0

```
$ svn --version
1.7.20
$ port installed | grep subversion
subversion @1.9.2_0 (active)
```

I also tried this:

```
$ sudo port select --set svn svn
Selecting 'svn' for 'svn' failed: The specified group 'svn' does not exist.
```

Comment: Run `type svn`. What does it give you?

Comment: it gives me svn is hashed (/usr/bin/svn)

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that this is a problem *using* a piece of software, as opposed to a development issue, and thus a better fit for Ask Different or SuperUser than StackOverflow -- you could (potentially) have the same problem with anything else installed through macports, even if it weren't a development tool.

Comment: well, there's your problem: It's not using `/opt/local/bin/svn` at all. Either open a new shell or run `hash -r`.

Comment: ...if neither of those helps, check your PATH to be sure `/opt/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Aces, hash -r did it!  Thanks for the quick input, and I will keep in mind your suggestion on where to post macport related questions.

Comment: ...to be clear, "hashed" means that it cached the location previously in the life of the same shell session -- and so isn't looking in the PATH again inside the same shell session unless the PATH changes or `hash -r` is run.

Comment: (...that the shell does this out-of-the-box is part of why the `LS=$(which ls)` idiom is so silly -- program locations are already cached, and in a manner much much more efficient than using a subshell calling an external tool!)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to just set your PATH such that cached values are invalidated.  You can do this by simply entering this at your bash prompt:

```
PATH=$PATH
```